# How to show grandchildren taxonomy term only in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy called: locations.

Locations go 4 levels deep:

United Kingdom >  England  > London > Wimbledon

We need to output the deepest taxonomy as text on a single post, outside of the loop.

So it just reads: Wimbledon

The code we have so far:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'locations', '', ', ', '' ) ); echo $terms_as_text; ?>
```

This currently outputs all locations. We need to show just the deepest.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `get_terms` insted, then get the las value of the array.

```
$terms = get_terms('locations', array('orderby' => 'none'));
echo end($terms);
```

Or if you need the terms inside the current post use `get_the_terms` function:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'locations' );
echo end($terms);
```

Comment: But we need to show the term as text, and it should only be at deepest level, I don't see how your code does that?

Comment: Did you proved the code? what code does is get all terms in an array, then you get the last value and show it.